# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have an unexpected token :
but i dont know why this is.

the code where it is happening.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.delete-btn').click(function() {
 $.ajax(function() {
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: { filename: filename },
    success: function(return) {
        if(return == 'SUCCESS') {
            $this = $(this).closest('tr');
            $this.remove();
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

I hope someone can find why i get the unexpeded token : at the url: 'ajax.php', rule.

Comment: `return` is a keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error is in your `success` callback. You've named the argument `return`, which is a reserved word. Call it something else.

---

Niet here, merging my answer into this one to complete the picture:

Change:

```
$.ajax(function() {
```

To:

```
$.ajax({
```

Pay closer attention to what you're writing :p

Comment: Good spot, +1 to yours for not just looking for a syntax error!

Comment: I've merged our answers, you can have the rep ^_^

Comment: this fixed my problem, thanks. now i only need to get it working. Will accept when i can.

Answer (score 1):

`return` is a reserved word in JavaScript. Use any other name other than return. I have used data instead of return. Also there is type is an error in ajax function you have written. updated the same. Use the below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.delete-btn').click(function() {
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: { filename: filename },
    success: function(data) {
        if(data == 'SUCCESS') {
            $this = $(this).closest('tr');
            $this.remove();
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed, so that people (especially OP) can understand what was wrong in the original.

Answer (score 0):

`return` is a keyword at javascript dont use it as a `variable name`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.delete-btn').click(function() {
     $.ajax(function() {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: { filename: filename },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data== 'SUCCESS') {
                $this = $(this).closest('tr');
                $this.remove();
            }
        }
    });
    });
    </script>
```